# Robot localization (IMU + GPS) position Without GPS

Tags: ros-kinetic, imu, robot-localization

I would like to get the GPS position based on the received GPS and the IMU that is at work (base_link). But I would like GPS to be calculated and when the real GPS disappears, that is, calculations based on IMU. How can this be done?
According to the navsat_transform_node instruction, it can only accept an absolute IMU.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to how I do it using IMU + wheel encoder data.  I'm not a pro, more like a hack, but when I lose RTK GPS for a brief moment I use wheel encoder data to continue to publish the odom statement.  A couple of us get together on Thursday's on a Zoom call to discuss this platform.

Example code: https://github.com/jones2126/ros1_lawn_tractor_ws/blob/master/src/ackermann_vehicle/nodes/odom_from_wheel_and_gps.py

Zoom meeting (Thursdays at Noon (US ET)) https://us02web.zoom.us/j/82088036016?pwd=K2lLc1FiWm9MU0dzRStxM2J2b3dpQT09#success